# Which is the proper & in a string?

Tags: html, image, ampersand

I have an image I am referring to in HTML5. It's name is "atmosphere-&-meteorology". When I refer to the , both `atmosphere-&-meteorology` and `atmosphere-&amp;-meteorology` show up fine for me. Which way is proper?

Comment: did you mean atmosphere-&-meteorology and atmosphere-&amp;-meteorology show up fine?

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow got rid of the amp; on the second string for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org).

In this case, if you use `atmosphere-&-meteorology`, it says

> `&` did not start a character reference. (`&` probably should have been
>   escaped as `&amp;`.)

However, if you use `atmosphere-&amp;-meteorology`, it says

> Congratulations! This document was successfully checked as HTML5!

Comment: Is the validator right? What requirement of the spec does it fall foul of? The spec says that character references must start with an ampersand. It doesn't say that an ampersand must start a character reference and, as far as I can see, it is only a parse error if the character following the ampersand is an alphanumeric.

Comment: @Alohci See [Tokenizing character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenizing-character-references). There is no character reference nor any error if `&` is followed by tab, LF, FF, space, less-than-sign, EOF, or sometimes an additional allowed character. Otherwise, it will be a character reference or a parse error.